# Adding double quote after each comma in string

Tags: c

I have string like below - and want to add double quote after each comma in my string.

I have tried to replace , with " ,\" " however it didnot work.

```
//orginal strign
char *mystring = "test,blabla,blabla,blabla";

//want to convert this format, after adding double quote
char *newstring = " test,\"blabla,\"blabbla,\"blabla";
```

How can I add double quote after each comman in string in C programming language?

Comment: What is the required output, and what are you getting?

Comment: What did you try that did not work?  We can’t help you fix your code if you don’t show it, and we don’t write code for you.  Are you running into problems because you were trying to modify string literals?  They usually can’t be changed and attempts to do so crash your program.

Comment: I will give "mystring" as a input and output should be like "newstring" as I described  above

Comment: *Before* each comma, or *after* each comma?

Comment: sorry , after each comma

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt *however it didnot work* what was wrong ? you can compare your solution with my answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I well understand you want something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  const char *mystring = "test,blabla,blabla,blabla";
  int n = 0;
  const char * p1;

  /* compute result length */
  for (p1 = mystring; *p1; ++p1)
    n += (*p1 == ',') ? 2 : 1;

  /* make result string */
  char * r = malloc(n + 1);
  char * p2 = r;

  for (p1 = mystring; *p1; ++p1) {
    if ((*p2++ = *p1) == ',')
      *p2++ = '"';
  }
  *p2 = 0;

  /* show it works */
  printf("%s\n", r);
  return 0;
}
```

That prints `test,"blabla,"blabla,"blabla`

---

If you want to have also the \ before the " as you say in the remark :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  const char *mystring = "test,blabla,blabla,blabla";
  int n = 0;
  const char * p1;

  /* compute result length */
  for (p1 = mystring; *p1; ++p1)
    n += (*p1 == ',') ? 3 : 1;

  /* make result string */
  char * r = malloc(n + 1);
  char * p2 = r;

  for (p1 = mystring; *p1; ++p1) {
    if ((*p2++ = *p1) == ',') {
      p2[0] = '\\';
      p2[1] = '"';
      p2 += 2;
    }
  }
  *p2 = 0;

  /* show it works */
  printf("%s\n", r);
  return 0;
}
```

That prints : `test,\"blabla,\"blabla,\"blabla`

Comment: yes its almost what I looking for , but need to add "\" as well before double quote

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt are you sure of that ? do you not confuse with what is needed to indicate to the compiler when you want a character quote rather than to say a string is starting/ending ?

Comment: string should be in that format ;char *mystring = "test,\"blabla,\"blabla,\"blabla";
I need to send this string in this format

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt when the compiler reads "test,\"blabla,\"blabla,\"blabla";" it makes the string *test,"blabla,"blabla,"blabla*, the \ disappear and are not part of the result. Anyway I edited my answer to also propose a solution adding the \ in the result as you can see

Comment: thanks for answer -btw how I do same thing if I was searching "bl" this time? will add \" again but this time will check "bl"  words instead of comma. from reverse

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt I think the best for you to learn is to find the solution by yourself that time, this is simple and very close to the case with ',' ;-)

Comment: ok, can you just explain "if ((*p2++ = *p1) == ',')" part ? why p2++ ?

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt that copies the character from _mystring_ into _r_, whatever it is ',' or not. When you don't understand when reading the source just execute the program into a debugger to be able to look at the variables/memory values where you want during the execution